# Inserting variables from Python into PostgreSQL statement

Tags: python, postgresql

A PostgreSQL table contains customer names and IDs.  I'm pulling IDs out of the table and running individual API calls for each customer.  This part works.

I'm having trouble taking the variables I'm pulling from one table and inserting them into the next table along with the data coming from the API call.

Ultimately I'm pulling down a list of active customers from Meraki's cloud and verifying admin accounts for each.  The problem is when I populate the PostgreSQL table with admins I don't know which row is for which customer.  I'm trying to slip in the customer name and ID from the initial API call as a reference.

I've tried a few different methods of syntax with no luck.  See the commented out sections in the code snippet below.  The insert_query variables are all methods I've tried.

```
    for row in records:
        customerid = row[0]
        customername = row[1]
        merakiurl = ("https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/" + customerid + "/admins")
        headers = {
        'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': apiMerakiKey
        }
        response = requests.request("GET", merakiurl, headers=headers)
        dictresponse=json.loads(response.text)
        fields = [
        'name', #Name
        'email', #E-mail
        'id',
        'networks',
        'tags',
        'twoFactorAuthEnabled',
        'lastActive',
        'accountStatus',
        'hasApiKey',
        'orgAccess'
        ]
        for item in dictresponse:
            my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
            #insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_adminlist VALUES (" + customerid + ", " + customername + ", %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            #insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_adminlist VALUES ({customerid}, {customername}, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_adminlist VALUES (" + {customerid} + "," + {customername} + ", %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
            connection.commit()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Notice the customerid and customername being defined at the beginning of the snippet.  Customerid is being used in the API call just after.

Then look at the insert_query variable under dictresponse.  I'm trying to add the two variables previously defined and add the actual API response into PostgreSQL.

This is the error when running the snippet exactly as indicated, using the third insert_query.

`Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL must be str, not set"`

Again, without trying to use customerid or customername this works fine.

*Edited after initial post*

The other option which may be feasible is to add the two variables into the dictionary itself and leave the PostgreSQL statement as is.  See below code snippet.

```
    for row in records:
        customerid = row[0]
        customername = row[1]
        merakiurl = ("https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/" + customerid + "/admins")
        headers = {
        'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': apiMerakiKey
        }
        response = requests.request("GET", merakiurl, headers=headers)
        dictresponse=json.loads(response.text)
        fields = [
        'customerid',
        'customername',
        'name', #Name
        'email', #E-mail
        'id',
        'networks',
        'tags',
        'twoFactorAuthEnabled',
        'lastActive',
        'accountStatus',
        'hasApiKey',
        'orgAccess'
        ]
        print(fields) #This is for testing only.  Remove once script works.
        for item in dictresponse:
            my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_adminlist VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
            connection.commit()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Problem here is customerid and customername don't exist in the API so this doesn't work.  I'm guessing there's a way to add something onto the `my_data =` section to cover it?

*Another Edit*

To clarify the output below is the data returned when running the script.  Note the 555555 and Company XYZ.  This is the data in row[0] and row[1].

`['555555', 'Company XYZ', 'name', 'email', 'id', 'networks', 'tags', 'twoFactorAuthEnabled', 'lastActive', 'accountStatus', 'hasApiKey', 'orgAccess']`

Notice the columns.  The data getting pulled from row 0 and 1 should be populating in customerid and customername columns. The data pulled from the API call should populate the rest.  555555 gets plugged into the API call.  I want to tell PostgreSQL the ID and customer name that was used for the subsequent data being pulled.  Otherwise I'm looking at a mass list of account info but don't know to whom it's associated.

```
meraki_automation=# select * from tbl_adminlist ;
 customerid | customername | name | email | id | networks | tags | twofactorauthenabled | lastactive | accountstatus | hasapikey | orgaccess 
------------+--------------+------+-------+----+----------+------+----------------------+------------+---------------+-----------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

When the script runs I get the following error:

`Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL '555555'`

It's because there's no column with that label.  I'm trying to input 555555 into the customerid column.

Comment: Do you put quotes around `customerid` and `customername` in the query?  Also are you sure of their datatype when it comes from `row[0]` and `row[1]`?

Try printing the query to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: I've been leaving quotes out of the query since it's a variable.  The print statement does print out the variables being queried from ```row[0]``` and ```row[1]```.  I inserted a print statement under ```for row in records``` and under ```for item in dictresponse```.

Comment: Just edited the original post.  An alternative option would be to insert the variables in the dictionary before the ```for item in ``` section happens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the literal string `customerid` or do you want a number representing the customer's id (like 5 or 6 or 19832)?  If so you need to use the variable as a variable and not just put the name of the variable in quotes.  Try:

```
fields = [
        row[0],
        row[1],
        'name', #Name
        'email', #E-mail
        'id',...
```

or something like that maybe?
It's a little hard to troubleshoot this question because there isn't an error message and I don't know what dictresponse is, nor what the query looks like once you print it out (can you show us?)

As a side, you don't need to `json.loads(`, there should be a `response.json()` method but this is a trivial aside compared to the greater problems you're having.

Keep at it & thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thanks.  I tried row[0] and row[1].  No dice.  I updated the post with additional detail.  ```dictresponse=json.loads(response.text)``` is handling the JSON response from the API call.

Comment: To answer your direct question I am looking for the customer's id.  It's contained in row[0] of the table.